# How to remove a consecutively repeating character in a string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Consider my input :-

```
"1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 14 14 14 11 11 11 2"
```

I want the output to be

```
"1 3 2 14 11 2"
```

Comment: uniq and squeeze method ... hard coding using index variables

Comment: @AshKashyap show us your efforts, StackOverflow it's not a write-code-for-me service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string_data = "1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 14 14 14 11 11 11 2"

string_data.split(' ').chunk(&:itself).collect(&:first).join(' ')
```

output will be `"1 3 2 14 11 2"`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
items = "1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 14 14 14 11 11 11 2"

items.split(' ').chunk(&:itself).collect(&:first)

#> ["1", "3", "2", "14", "11", "2"]
```